# Is there a way to predefine a backlog queue in simpy?

Tags: simpy

I am exploring the use of Simpy to model the queue of elective surgery demand following Covid. Here I want to explore various strategies, such as number of theatres, on the cutting through the existing backlog. Is there any way to predefine a queue length and waiting time distribution in Simpy? I imagine I can create a source of patients to create the waiting list size and hold off serving them until I reach the required queue size and waiting list distribution, but wondering if there are any more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can put what ever timestamp you want on your backlog objects and added them directly to the queue at start up, but you will still need to delay your queue processing with a timeout to start it at the right time